# Alternate string ID for Guid ID objects

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, indexing

I currently use `Guid` as the primary key for my `ContentItem`s in my code-first Entity Framework `Context`. However, since `Guid` are so unwieldy I would like to also set an alternate, friendly ID for each `ContentItem` (or descendant of `ContentItem`) according to the following logic:

1. Use the `Name` property, to lower, replacing whitespace with a `-` , and end the prefix with a `-` as well
2. Look in the database to see which other `ContentItem` have a `FriendlyID` with the same prefix, and find the one with the highest numeric suffix
3. Increment that by 1 and add as a suffix

So the first item with name "Great Story" would have `FriendlyID` of `great-story-1`, the next one `great-story-2`, and so forth.

I realize there are a number of ways to implement this sort of thing, but here are my questions:

1. Is it advisable to explicitly set a new field with the alternate ID according to this logic, or should I just run a query each time applying the same rules as I would to generate the ID to find the right object?
2. How should I enforce the setting of the alternate ID? Should I do it in my service methods for each content item at creation time? (This concerns me because if someone forgets to add that logic to the service method, now the object doesn't have a `FriendlyID`) Or should I do it in the model itself, with a property with manually-defined getters/setters that have to query the DB and find out what the next available `FriendlyID` is?
3. Are there alternatives to using this sort of `FriendlyID` for the purpose of making human-friendly URL's and web service requests? The ultimate purpose of this thing is really so that we can have users go to `http://awesomewebsite.com/Content/great-story-1` and get sent to the right content item, rather than `http://awesomewebsite.com/Content/f0be271e-ee01-48de-8599-ddd602e777b6`, etc.

Comment: Can a Name change or an item be deleted or retired? If so, do you want the FriendlyId to be stable? When a user comes back with a 5 year old link what is the expected behavior? My guess is that it should be stored and not generated on-the-fly. And that you need to keep all of the values previously used so that you don't reuse them.

Comment: Look at the url of this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593139/alternate-string-id-for-guid-id-objects

Comment: @HABO - good point. You're right - even if I sorted the results that came back by `CreatedDate`, say, if any got deleted it would throw the whole scheme off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pre-generate them. This allows you to index them. I understand your concern but there's no alternative in practice. (I have done this.)
2. I don't know the architecture of your app. Just note, that generating such an ID requires database query access. It probably shouldn't be done as a property or method on the entity itself.
3. You could use a combination by putting both a "speaking name" *and* and ID into the URL. I have seen sites do this. For GUID ID's this is not exactly pretty, though.

Write yourself a few helper methods to generate such string IDs in a convenient and robust way. That way it is not that much trouble doing this.

Comment: Thanks, especially on point #2. This was my main concern (about trying to do it in the model itself).